# dockerized postgres and dockerized Spring boot app

Tags: spring, postgresql, docker, spring-boot, dockerfile

my application.properties file

```
server.port=8085
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://init-postgres:5432/dbname
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

and for dockerizing postgres I'm using command

```
docker run -d -p 5432:5432 --name init-postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=dbname -e POSTGRES_USER=username -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password postgres
```

but it gives **java.net.UnknownHostException: init-postgres**
I'm beginner with Docker and learning it from a tutorial. to dockerized Postgresql & Spring boot app communication.

Comment: The url should use `localhost`... The container name will only work if you are also dockerizing your spring boot application and run them in the same network.

Comment: @M. Denium how I'll be able to generate docker image using mvn install because whenever I fire this command it gives an error java.net.UnknownHostException & build is failed

Comment: As stated use `localhost`...

Answer (score 1):

**If you need to dockerize both of them without docker-compose**

application.config

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://init-postgres:5432/dbname`

1. Create network

`docker network create mynet`

2. Run postgres container with created network

`docker run --net mynet --name init-postgres  -d -e POSTGRES_DB=dbname -e POSTGRES_USER=username -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -p 5432:5432 postgres`

2. Create **jar** archive

```
mvn clean
mvn compile
mvn package
```

3. Create dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/<HERE_IS_NAME_OF_YOUR_JAR_FILE>.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} myapp.jar
EXPOSE 8085
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar" , "/myapp.jar"]
```

4. Build spring boot image myapp

`docker build -t myapp .`

5. Run spring boot container

`docker run --name myapp-container --net mynet -p 8080:8080 myapp`

Answer (score 0):

**If your application runs on the host without docker and your database lives inside a docker container**, you need to change this line:

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://init-postgres:5432/dbname`

with

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname`

instead, **if both the application and the database are running on docker** you need to refer with the docker container name, as you stated above in the snippet you posted.

I suggest to use `docker-compose`, it's a handy tool that can ease the difficulties of deployment and it's useful when developing too since it allows to bring up & down your application without too much hassle. In the [official docker website](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) there is a nice introduction to the tool with examples.